# DRLS in Salesforce Professional edition

Tags: roll-up-summary

Is it possible to use DRLS in Salesforce Professional edition(PE)?
I've found the article that describes that it is easy using Process builder. However, here is an issue, there is no way to invoke Apex classes from Process Builder in PE. I wonder if there is a way to apply such a great tool to Pro edition?

Comment: BTW, there is a [chatter group for DLRS](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009O5pCAE) in the Success Community.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the managed package version of DLRS and that should (unless I'm missing something) support professional edition due being security reviewed and aloha enabled, as mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)

If it wasn't "aloha", or as its shown on the installed page "counts against limits" = unchecked, it wouldn't support professional edition, but that package permission lets you install a package containing apex into PE. (Conditions apply about other features though, this doesn't make all packages PE-compatbile)

I also believe that the real-time mode will not be supported as there's no way to generate the apex triggers that mode needs - they have to be unmanaged since they're tightly coupled to the type of object, and that won't be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not since you can't run triggers from PE edition since you don't have API access. Now, if you installed a managed package that's similar from an ISV, rather than the unmanaged package, you'd be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The package was installed successfully. The documentation says that Apex classes from Managed Packages can be called in PE, but Process builder does not have such an option. It is confusing me.

Comment: In PE, you're allowed to create a limited number of Processes (3 or 4 as I recall). DLRS is not a managed package. It's unmanaged. If it was a managed package, then you'd be able to use it. There's something similar that IS a managed package which is a paid product, but not all packages are enabled for PE. You'll need to check the documentation for each package.